# Как скролить фиксированный блок, если он не влезает на экран?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Собственно есть мобильное меню с position: fixed, в нем много пунктов меню, которые не влезают на экран моб телефона, но при попытке проскрулить вниз, скрулится вся страница но не этот блок с меню.
Пример, думаю, приводить не стоит в коде, надеюсь меня поймут. Как с этим бороться?

На мобильном телефоне скролится страница, но не меню.

Comment: добавить элементу min_width, или min_height, чтобы у него при маленьких размерах появлялись полосы прокрутки

Comment: Не помогает, вот пример: http://www.mactedesign.com/ при разрешении меньше 768 появляется меню.

Comment: не вижу, что не так. Добавляй в вопрос **всю необходимую** информацию. Иначе можно долго гадать, что именно ты имел ввиду

Comment: Добавил, на моб телефоне скролится страница, но не меню. Хотя высота задана.

Comment: понятнее абсолютно не стало. А также, непонятно чем не устраивает решение из первого комментария. Код приводить не буду, ты и так должен понять :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить блоку что-нибудь вроде:

```
max-height: 100vh;
overflow-y: auto;
```

Comment: Спасибо, то, что нужно!

Answer (score 0):

Значения max-height и min-height, безусловно приведены для примера.

```
   .cont-mob{
     max-height: 100px;
     overflow: auto;
   }

   .slicknav_menu{
     min-height:200px;
   }
```